# pyqtgraph cross widget to plot not working?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am trying to add `GraphicsLayoutWidget`  and `LinearRegionItem`, that two ratio is 4:1 or m:n, but I don't found any layout in `pygtgraph`.So I try to the code like below, but unfortunately it don't work and cast out traceback error info.

**code**

```py
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Chart(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.data = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
        self.data = np.sin(self.data)
        self.p = self.addPlot(y=self.data)

class LR(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self, target):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = self.addPlot()  # type:pg.PlotItem
        self.target = target  # type: pg.PlotItem

        rg = (target.data[0], target.data[-1])
        self.p.setXRange(rg[0], rg[1], padding=0)
        self.lr = pg.LinearRegionItem([rg[0], rg[1]])
        self.lr.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.onLRChanged)
        self.p.addItem(self.lr)

    def onLRChanged(self):
        print(self.target, self.lr.getRegion())
        self.target.setXRange(*self.lr.getRegion())


class Win(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        lay = QVBoxLayout()

        self.chart = Chart()
        self.lr = LR(self.chart)

        lay.addWidget(self.chart)
        lay.addWidget(self.lr)

        lay.setStretch(0, 4)
        lay.setStretch(1, 1)
        self.setLayout(lay)


app = QApplication([])
win = Win()
win.show()
app.exec()
```

**image**
[image]

**error**
The traceback info will show when user drag `LinearRegionItem` line in both side of the bottom graph(plot)
[image]

**environment**
Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Name: pyqtgraph Version: 0.12.2
Name: numpy Version: 1.20.3
Name: PyQt5 Version: 5.15.4

Comment: I don't get any error, what version of pyqtgraph do you use?

Comment: @eyllanesc update enviroment info in my post.

Comment: @eyllanesc The traceback info will show when user drag `LinearRegionItem`  line in both side of the bottom graph(plot).

Comment: Your approach is the one that confused me since you say that the stretching factor caused the error but that is not true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the stretch factor but setting the range to the GraphicsLayoutWidget that expects a QRect, instead of the PlotItem that expects a tuple causing that exception. On the other hand you can improve how to place the initial range based on the range of the data, also it is better to use signals.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

import pyqtgraph as pg

import numpy as np


class Chart(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    def __init__(self, xdata, ydata):
        super().__init__()
        self.p = self.addPlot(x=xdata, y=ydata)


class LR(pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget):
    range_changed = pyqtSignal(float, float)

    def __init__(self, xmin, xmax):
        super().__init__()
        self.lr = pg.LinearRegionItem(values=(xmin, xmax))
        self.p = self.addPlot()
        self.p.addItem(self.lr)
        self.lr.sigRegionChanged.connect(self.handle_region_changed)

    def handle_region_changed(self, item):
        self.range_changed.emit(*item.getRegion())


class Win(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        xdata = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, 100)
        ydata = np.sin(xdata)

        self.chart = Chart(xdata, ydata)
        self.lr = LR(xdata.min(), xdata.max())
        self.lr.range_changed.connect(self.chart.p.setXRange)

        lay = QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.chart, stretch=4)
        lay.addWidget(self.lr, stretch=1)


def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    win = Win()
    win.show()
    app.exec()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I found my method can also work, I had made a low mistake that I  shoud change `onLRChanged` at `self.target.p.setXRange(*self.lr.getRegion())`